# PHP XML encoding

Tags: php, xml, encode

I need a function that will convert € or chr(0x20AC) or chr(8364) to `&#8364;` without having a static map.

I tried using `htmlentities()`, but it only seems to work for the symbol itself and it converts to `&euro;`.

Comment: What do you want to convert it to?  Not to mention that chr only works with ASCII characters (0 - 255).  If you wanted to represent it with chr, you'd need to split it `chr(0x20).chr(0xAC)`...

Comment: What character encoding is the input and what the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ircmaxwell kind of answered the question in a round about way... what i was trying to do really isn't possible.  I have circumvented the process by requiring the user to utilize the html entity instead.